# show values in spinner using soap method

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-studio

I want to show data form web services to spinner but the data not show in spinner please help me out this is my code.

Main activity Code:

```
public class AgentProgress extends Activity {

    Spinner sp1,sp2;
    ListView ls1;
    ProgressBar pbbar;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    static final String KEY_TABLE = "AGENTDATA";
    static final String KEY_AGENT_NAME = "Parent_Agent_Name";// parent node
    static final String KEY_BRANCH_NAME = "Branch_Name";// parent node
    static final String KEY_UW_YEAR = "Uw_Year";
    static final String KEY_CONTRIBUTION = "Contribution";
    static final String KEY_ADJ = "Adj";
    static final String KEY_TARGET = "Target";
    static final String KEY_DEF = "DEF";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agent_progress);

        sp1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnames);
        sp2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spyear);
        ls1= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstproducts);
        pbbar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
        FillList f=new FillList();
        f.execute("");
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }

    public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            WebServiceCAll com = new WebServiceCAll();
            final String string1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Agentid");
            String strXml = com.LoadAgent("LoadAgent");
            try {







                //messageBox("test", strXml);
                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(strXml); // getting DOM element

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TABLE);
                //String[] arList = null;
                //String[] arListkey = null;
                //  int conttotal=0;
                // looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_AGENT_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_AGENT_NAME));
                    //map.put(KEY_BRANCH_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BRANCH_NAME));

                    //map.put(KEY_UW_YEAR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_UW_YEAR));
                    //map.put(KEY_CONTRIBUTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CONTRIBUTION));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    menuItems.add(map);

                    //messageBox("test", "fahad");

                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Error", "", ex);
            }
            return strXml;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {

                SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(AgentProgress.this, menuItems,  R.layout.activity_agent_progress,
                        new String[]{"Parent_Agent_Name"},new int[]{R.id.spnames});

                    mSchedule.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    sp1.setAdapter(mSchedule);


            } catch (Exception exception) {
                //Toast.makeText(Login.this,exception.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Error", "", exception);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Soap class code:

```
public String LoadAgent(String MethodName)
    {

        try {
            SOAP_ACTION = namespace + MethodName;

            //Adding values to request object
            request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);
            //Adding String value to request object
            SetEnvelope();

            try {


                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
                return result;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
                return e.toString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return e.toString();
        }

    }
```

please help me out. this is the code please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you are not running the necessary code in the UI thread, provided you are getting the correct data back.  I'd suggest changing your code a bit and making the array adapter a member variable, assign it to the spinner in the onCreate and then calling notify once the data has been added.

I've tried to provide a brief example:

```
public class AgentProgress extends Activity {

   Spinner sp1,sp2;
   ListView ls1;
   ProgressBar pbbar;
   ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;
   List<String> spinnerData = new ArrayList<>();

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agent_progress);

    sp1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnames);
    sp2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spyear);

    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerData );

    ls1= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstproducts);
    pbbar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
    FillList f=new FillList();
    f.execute("");
    pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }
```

In your AsyncTask:

```
   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

     ...

     spinnerData.add('your data');
     ...
     }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

     mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
     });


    }
```